# Permutations sum eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

In a recent question [Quadrilateral angles](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3865447/angles-in-an-inscriptible-quadrilateral)
an answer by M. Jean Marie uses computer verification. To get the right same fact i wanted to prove the following:

If $P$ is a permutation matrix and $C$ the cycle permutation ($i\to i+1$) all of dimension $n$ can we say (prove) something about $\lambda(P+CP)\neq -2$

Perhaps from Perron-Frobenius theory or else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrix $(I+C)P$ is a primitive matrix because every 'vertex' can reach any other within $n$ steps. [Any vertex $x_i$ is reachable via $(I+C)P$ by two vertices, namely $P^{-1}x_i$ and $P^{-1}x_{i-1}$.]

Therefore by the Perron Frobenius theory, there is a unique Perron root equal to $\lambda_{max}((I+C)P)$ and no other eigenvalue has the same absolute value.

But $\|(I+C)P\|=\|I+C\|=2$ since $P$ is a permutation/orthogonal matrix, $\|I+C\|\le1+\|C\|=2$, and $(I+C)P\mathbf{1}=2\mathbf{1}$ (where $\mathbf{1}=(1,\ldots,1)$).

Hence $-2$ cannot be an eigenvalue of $(I+C)P$.